# How to write "at least n" and "exactly n" in logical notation?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

$$
\exists x \exists y \exists z (x\neq y  \land x \neq z \land y \neq z \land P(x) \land P(y) \land P(z))
$$

I would translate the above sentence as, "There exist *3 different* elements (x,y,z) for which P(x), P(y), and P(z) are true."

Does this mean *at least 3* elements or *exactly 3* elements? I think it's at least 3.

If so, how do I formally write *exactly 3* elements?

Comment: I may be rusty at this.  $\exists!a$ means "there exists a unique a" so I'd think $\exists ! \{x,y,z\} (x\neq y  \land x \neq z \land y \neq z \land P(x) \land P(y) \land P(z))$ would mean "there exists a unique **set** of three elements so that ...".  That should do it shouldn't it?  If there were four such elements there'd be another set of three we could make...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$P$ holds for **at least** three elements:
$$\exists x\exists y\exists z\ [x\ne y\land x\ne z\land y\ne z\land P(x)\land P(y)\land P(z)]$$
$P$ holds for **at most** three elements:
$$\forall w\forall x\forall y\forall z\ [P(w)\land P(x)\land P(y)\land P(z)\to (w=x\lor w=y\lor w=z\lor x=y\lor x=z\lor y=z)]$$
$P$ holds for **exactly** three elements:
$$\exists x\exists y\exists z\forall w\ [x\ne y\land x\ne z\land y\ne z\land (P(w)\leftrightarrow(w=x\lor w=y\lor w=z))]$$

Answer (score 0):

It says "at least three elements". Imagine a structure with four elements in which $P$ is true for all of them; clearly the sentence is satisfied in this structure.

A quick way to say "precisely three" is "at least three, and *not* at least four".

Comment: So something like:
(∃x∃y∃z) ∧ ¬(∃x∃y∃z∃w) ?

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Yes! With inside of those parentheses the inequalities and the predicates, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Something like
$$\forall a\,\big(P(a)\Rightarrow (a=x)\vee (a=y)\vee (a=z)\big)$$
says that the property $P(a)$ is only satisfied if $a=x,y,z$.

Comment: Notice that when $P(x)$ denotes `x=x+1` (so, $P(x)$ is categorically false), the OP's given sentence is false whereas your suggested sentence is true.

Answer (score 0):

First establish a set B to which $x,y,z$ may belong then

\begin{equation}
\exists A\subset B\,(\,\vert A\vert=3 \land (\wedge_{x\in A}P(x)\,)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Okay, no-ones suggesting this and maybe it isn't valid but...

isn't $\exists ! a$ meaning there exists a unique $a$ acceptable, and....

isn't $\exists \{a,b,c\}$ meaning there exists a set f three elements acceptable?

If so (and maybe those notations *aren't* acceptable) wouldn't $\exists! \{x,y,z\} ...$ do it?  There is a unique set of three elements where the conditions hold so there are three elements.  If there were 4 or more elements where the conditions hold and we can make multiple different sets of 3 where the conditions hold.  But as any set of three must be unique, there can only be those three elements.

Comment: $\exists!a$ is perfectly fine notation, but it's in an *extension* of first-order logic, or it's an *abbreviation* for something in first-order logic. I may be wrong but I assumed the OP wanted a formula in the primitive notation of standart first-order logic. As for your notation $\exists\{a,b,c\},$ I don't think it's standard (at least I've never seen it before), and there is the problem that $\{a,b,c\}$ does not necessarily denote a set of three *distinct* elements.

Comment: Valid comments.

Answer (score 0):

> $$ \exists x \exists y \exists z (x\neq y  \land x \neq z \land y \neq z \land P(x) \land P(y) \land P(z)) \tag1$$
>
> I would translate the above sentence as, "There exist *3 different*
> elements (x,y,z) for which P(x), P(y), and P(z) are true." Does this mean *at least 3* elements or *exactly 3* elements?

Sentence $(1)$ means that $P(x)$ is true of **3 particular objects**, which is equivalent to saying that it is true of **at least 3 objects**. (Strictly speaking, $P(x)$ being true of 3 objects is also equivalent.)

1. Being true of 3 particular objects does not preclude them being duplicate indistinguishable objects, so arguably ***neither*** implies *3 different objects* ***nor*** implies *3 distinct objects*.

   (On the other hand, 'different'/'distinct' can be understood as 'separate', in which case '3 different objects', '3 distinct objects', '3 particular objects' and 'at least 3 objects' are interchangeable.)
2. Sentence $(1)$ has not actually identified any three particular objects; $x,y,z$ are just dummy variables.
3. Being true of 3 particular objects does not preclude being true of 7 particular objects, so does ***not*** imply being true of *exactly 3 objects*, which can be formalised as $$∃a\:∃b\:∃c\:\Big(a\ne b\,∧\, a\ne c\,∧\,b\ne c\,∧\,∀s\,\big(P(s)\,↔\,s= a\,\lor\, s=b\,\lor\, s=c\big)\Big).\tag2$$

Sentence $(1)$ is logically equivalent to this more concise sentence: $$∀a\:∀b\:∃s\:\big(s\ne a\,∧\,s\ne b\,∧\,P(s)\big).$$