# Equivalent to DL Number Restrictions in FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I would like to express the same constraints than the Number Restrictions of Description Logics in First Order Logics: at-least and at-most. I find this [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936315/how-to-write-in-logical-notation-at-least-n-elements-and-exactly-n-elements?newreg=3b4e8e7e97664964becc7062ee9aa35c), but I would like to have a solution for any n. Is this possible? I know that DL are less expressive than FOL, so I do not doubt that it is possible, but I don’t know how to write them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general "definition" of "*there is at least/at most/exactly $n$...*" is possible only with recursion.

Let  $\exists^{1}xP(x)\Leftrightarrow\exists xP(x)$. Then:

- There are at least $n$ different $x$'s such that $P(x)$:
  $$\exists^{n}xP(x)\Leftrightarrow\exists x\left[P(x)\wedge\exists^{n-1}y\left(x\neq y\wedge P(y)\right)\right]$$
  for $n\in\mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$.
- There are at most $n$ different $x$'s such that $P(x)$:
  $$\neg\exists^{n+1}xP(x)$$
  for $n\in\mathbb{N}-\{0\}$
- There are exactly $n$ different $x$'s such that $P(x)$:
  $$\exists^{n}xP(x)\wedge\neg\exists^{n+1}xP(x)$$
  for $n\in\mathbb{N}-\{0\}$

Comment: Thanks! There is one thing I’m not sure to understand. In the definition of at least, how can we be sure that two non-consecutive elements are different?

Comment: What do you mean with "non-consecutive elements"? There is no ordering of the elements here. $\exists^{n-1}y\left(x\neq y\wedge P(y)\right)$ means "*there are $(n-1)$-many hings such that, if $y$ is one of them, $P(y)$  and $y\neq\ x$*". So, together with $x$, there are $n$ such things, witch is the same as "there are at least $n$ such things".

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I’m not really familiar with recursive existence operator. Thanks for the answer!