# Expressing the size of a set in logical notation

Tags: logic

I want to express the fact that a set has *at most* 2 elements, in logical notation. Is the following correct:

$$\exists x_1 \exists x_2 \exists x_3(x_1=x_2 \lor x_1=x_3 \lor x_2=x_3)$$

Or must I use universal quantifiers (which would seem to be correct, given that the above statement is the negation of *at least* 3 elements). Thank you.

Comment: You can do it much simpler by saying $\exists x_1\exists x_2: x_1\neq x_2$. In your case $x_1=x_2=x_3$ - which would lead to only 1 element - is not excluded.

Comment: @LegNaiB Doesn't your expression say that there are at least 2 distinct elements? And I don't think OP's expression implies that $x_1 = x_2 = x_3$. For instance, we could have $x_1=x_2=0$ and $x_3 = 1$.

Comment: It doesn't imply that, but it is a possibility. But you are correct, I interchanged "at most" and "at least". However, the third element is not necessary. It would be enough to just say $\exists x_1\exists x_2$. Just the case of zero elements is not included then.

Comment: See the accepted answer in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936315/how-to-write-in-logical-notation-at-least-n-elements-and-exactly-n-elements?

Answer (score 1):

The following set satisfies your sentence: $\{0, 1, 2\}$ where we take $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 0$. In fact, any nonempty set would satisfy that sentence. You could modify your sentence to use universal rather than existential quantifiers.

$$
\forall x_1 \forall x_2 \forall x_3(x_1=x_2 \lor x_1=x_3 \lor x_2=x_3)
$$

This sentence being true means that among any choice of 3 elements in the set, there must be some pair that is the same. In other words, it expresses the property that the set cannot have more than 3 elements.